# Commutative Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This is a very general question.

Do we need to check the existence of a multiplicative inverse to prove if a set forms a commutative ring?

This is unclear in the book I am reading.

Comment: Usually most elements of a ring won't have a multiplicative inverse. Think about $\mathbb{Z}$, for instance.

Comment: Ask yourself: Where do multiplicative inverses appear in the definition of a ring?

Comment: Do you mean "a multiplicative inverse" or do you mean "a multiplicative identity"?

Comment: A ring needs neither multiplicative identity nor multiplicative inverse.

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is no.

You don't need to have multiplicative inverses in order to have multiplicative commutativity in a ring.

An excellent example is the Integers, which is a commutative ring without multiplicative inverses.

Comment: In the example I am reading there is a 2x2 matrix in the form:

[ a c 0 a]  and in the proof they wrote that the matrix is invertible only if its 


determinant does not equal 0 so a $\neq$0. Why is it necessary to state this in a commutative ring proof?

Comment: This doesn't make much sense to me. Could you post a picture of the page maybe?

Comment: @combostudent That statement in your comment is not true for general commutative rings. It's true if the entries are from a field, though. This is a standard way of detecting units in a ring of matrices over a field. They probably did this just to tell you what the units of your ring are.

Comment: @combostudent It's just a tangential remark  (unrelated to verifying *ring* structure)